# Angular.js error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm working on a project where I'm trying to allow me to upload weather data from an .xls file to an SQL database.  It's my first time using Angularjs so I used a tutorial and everything seemed to work fine.

```
My code is:

<head>
<title>.: Import Data with AngularJS :.</title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="C:\Users\Bryan\source\repos\Weather\weather\Scripts\jquery-
1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="C:\Users\Bryan\source\repos\Weather\weather\Scripts\angular.min.js">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" 
src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular-
route.min.js"
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="C:\Users\Bryan\source\repos\Weather\weather\Scripts\bootstrap.min.js">
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.cs
s">
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="C:\Users\Bryan\source\repos\Weather\weather\Scripts\ImportData.js">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" 
src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.11.5/xlsx.full.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.11.5/jszip.js"></script>
```

Everything goes well but I get the following errors:

```
ImportData.html:7 GET http://localhost:9000/Content/bootstrap.min.css 
net::ERR_ABORTED
ImportData.html:1 Not allowed to load local resource: ImportData.js
angular.js:88 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] 
at angular.js:88
at angular.js:4957
at p (angular.js:410)
at g (angular.js:4917)
at gb (angular.js:4839)
at c (angular.js:1949)
at Uc (angular.js:1970)
at xe (angular.js:1855)
at angular.js:33826
at HTMLDocument.b (angular.js:3468)
```

I've read that bootstrap and angular can conflict, but take it out and it still seems to error out.  Any ideas where the error is?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: check your network tab and post your controller code

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to load resources from your local computer. Try giving path as relative that will solve your issue. Also use base url in html if you want to control base url for all requests from your app.

Answer (score 0):

Your files are not able to fetch by the browser from the mentioned locations. So better way to give relative paths i.e. "../../ImportData.js".
Also It shows injector module error that means, Angular file is missing and its module is not able to find the libraries.

You can try replacing all the file paths with as well. Also this http://localhost:9000/Content/bootstrap.min.css 
net::ERR_ABORTED 
is due to the internet failure or due to your firewall restrictions. So, you can replace this with "https" instead of 'http'.

Try these options. There's problem with file links only.